# How is the best way to delete a tenant in WSO2 carbon?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to delete a tenant using the method "deleteTenant" in the class "TenantMgtAdminServiceStub" but it didn't works, it shows an error. I'm wondering if this is the best way to delete a tenant... I was looking for help and I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548968/how-to-delete-tenants-in-wso2-identity-server) but is not a possibility restart the server every time I want to delete a tenant.

Days before I [post this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500367/wso2-carbon-error-deleting-a-tenant) with the error I got when I use that method.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 Carbon: Error deleting a tenant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500367/wso2-carbon-error-deleting-a-tenant)

Answer (score 3):

Tenants once created from the UI cannot be deleted from the UI. However, Using the deleteTenant operation of RemoteTenantManagerService we can delete a tenant. This am basing on a product like API-Manager1.9.0

To access this RemoteTenantManagerService as https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteTenantManagerService?wsdl follow the following steps

step1: set the following property to false in vi ../repository/conf/carbon.xml       `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>`

step2: start the server and then access https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteTenantManagerService?wsdl via soap ui

step3: if a tenant is created each tenant should have a tenant id which we need to pass

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:deleteTenant>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:tenantId>?</ser:tenantId>
      </ser:deleteTenant>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note: if you are to create a tenant with the same name you will need to restart the server

regards,shavantha

Comment: what should be done if you are getting UNauthorized during delete operation?