# wso2 Identity Server - Unable to delete tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

i'm trying to delete a tenant via the TenantMgtAdminService but it is not possible. I tried to do it with both the tenant active/inactive and used both superadmin and tenant admin credentials. I have tried dropping the database and recreating it to ensure data is not corrupted. The only thing i did was create this tenant.

The error i get is below:

```
[2017-02-13 15:15:27,525] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService} -  Error deleting tenant with domain: testdomain.com and tenant id: 1.
    is_1    | java.lang.Exception: Error in notifying tenant addition.
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.notifyTenantDeletion(TenantMgtAdminService.java:139)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.deleteTenant(TenantMgtAdminService.java:568)
    is_1    |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    is_1    |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    is_1    |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    is_1    |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    is_1    |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    is_1    |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    is_1    |   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    is_1    |   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    is_1    |   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    is_1    |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    is_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    is_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    is_1    |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    is_1    |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    is_1    | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.exception.StratosException: Error occurred while revoking the access tokens in tenant 1
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.onPreDelete(OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.java:76)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.util.TenantMgtUtil.triggerPreTenantDelete(TenantMgtUtil.java:119)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.notifyTenantDeletion(TenantMgtAdminService.java:135)
    is_1    |   ... 60 more
    is_1    | Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error occurred while retrieving 'ACTIVE or EXPIRED' access tokens for user  tenant id : 1
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.getAccessTokensOfTenant(TokenMgtDAO.java:1702)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.onPreDelete(OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.java:42)
    is_1    |   ... 62 more
    is_1    | Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'USER_DOMAIN' in field list is ambiguous
    is_1    |   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    is_1    |   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    is_1    |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    is_1    |   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    is_1    |   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.getAccessTokensOfTenant(TokenMgtDAO.java:1661)
    is_1    |   ... 63 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use RemoteTenantManagerService service to delete a tenant. Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553984/how-is-the-best-way-to-delete-a-tenant-in-wso2-carbon

Comment: Indeed for some reason the RemoteTenantManagerService works and the TenantMgtAdminService doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Pubci's comment on my question, using the RemoteTenantManagerService instead of the TenantMgtAdminService works.

Answer (score 0):

@Orfeas Panagou: I am not sure about your set-up if you are using any RDMS database with WSO2 IS for user management then you can give a try by removing required tenant from "[UM_TENANT]" table.

Comment: Removing data from the database directly can't be recommended as it can break functionality and consistency. So make it the very very last option.